# Deleting document doesn't work in a mongoose pre('remove') hook

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to delete a Book which has references to the chapters. When I delete the book, I want all the related chapters removed along with it. But I have been unsuccessful in removing the chapter documents from the DB. Here is how I am removing it.

First is the controller method:

```
exports.delete = async(req, res) => {
  const book = await Book.findOne({ id: req.params.id});
  await book.remove();
  res.redirect(`/`);
}
```

After that, the `pre('remove')` hook gets triggered:

```
bookSchema.pre('remove', function(next){
  Chapter.findOneAndRemove({book_id: this.id});
  next();
});
```

I have also tried `document.remove()` and `Model.deleteMany()` but the documents are still there. There are no errors and the hook middleware is triggered. I realize that in the code example I am only removing one document instead of documents but even that does not work. The book gets deleted from the DB but the chapters remain.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`remove()` or `deleteMany()` are async functions you should use async/await or callbacks before calling the `next()` middleware:

```
bookSchema.pre('remove', async function(next) {
    await Chapter.deleteMany({book_id: this._id}).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });
    next();
});
```